# CloudFlare: Cannot remove TXT record with the value "ca3-xxxxxxxx"

Tags: cloudflare, spf, dig

I checked the DNS records on the digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=mydomain.com&type=TXT&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=

The Dig shows two TXT records but but **I don't have the first record**: (ca3-0158c3e5584b4fdba369cf3efeb6c56a)

**Dig shows:**
mydomain.com@8.8.4.4 (Default):

```
mydomain.com.       299 IN  TXT "ca3-0158c3e5584b4fdba369cf3efeb6c56a"
mydomain.com.       299 IN  TXT "v=spf1 redirect=_spf.yandex.net"
```

This web site is on the CloudFlare. **DNS records:** http://prntscr.com/r2m9ln

What can be reason and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: @ChristophKluge, 
Sad to say that but yes. Do you have any ideas?

The current settings: see please, http://prntscr.com/r6rb3k

Answer (score 1):

the mentioned TXT record which starts with "ca3-" is a CloudFlare internal record which they use for TLS validation. I guess since they need it to make their services available to you, there is no chance to delete it.

There is several posts inside the CloudFlare community about it: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/unable-to-see-and-remove-txt-record/44179/5

Comment: Thank you. I asked them. If it is really impossible, I'll have to remove the CF because mails are rejected by receivers.

Comment: Do you have the rejection message of the receivers and the Mail headers? I could try to give you some helping hands if you want.

Comment: Yes, I have, and I would be grateful. How can I share with you the mail headers as private?

Comment: **details.txt**

`Reporting-MTA: dns; forward101p.mail.yandex.net
X-Yandex-Queue-ID: 236BE32813B0
X-Yandex-Sender: rfc822; me@mydomain.com
Arrival-Date: Tue, 11 Feb 2020 10:25:47 +0300 (MSK)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; Bauservice.BA@web.de
Original-Recipient: rfc822;Bauservice.BA@web.de
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; mx-ha02.web.de
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554-Transaction failed 554-Reject due to policy
    restrictions. 554 For explanation visit
    https://web.de/email/senderguidelines?ip=77.88.28.101&c=hd`

Comment: and **Undelivered Message Headers.txt**

http://prntscr.com/r7xmck